# Apply condition hasMany in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables: `users`, `meeting_types` and `user_meeting_types`

Now I want to apply a query on `users` table and pass condition in `user_meeting type`

`User` has many meetings and meeting has one `meeting_type`

How I can apply conditions on user and user_meeting_type and get data from all tables?

I want data from all the tables

The query is like this:

```
Select * from users left join user_meeting_types on user.id = user_meeting_types.user_id left join meeting_types on user_meeting_types.meeting_id = meeting_type.id where user.id = 37 and user_meeting_type.meeting_id = 5
```

user.rb

```
class User
  has_many :UserMeetingType
```

user_meeting_type.rb

```
class UserMeetingType
  belongs_to :UserMeeting
```

Comment: show the actual model and relationships you defined one them. That will help quick answering

Comment: I confess I don't understand what you need. You need to reformulate your model names, I am assuming you have `user`, `meeting` and `meeting_type`. The "user" prefix for meeting is not necessary unless you have other types, and still, there are other ways to do that. 
What do the models have? What data do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The models are the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_meeting_types
end

class MeetingType < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UserMeetingType < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :meeting_type
end
```

First you have to fetch the user:

```
user = User.find(37) # Select * from users where id = 37
```

Then for recovering the specifics user_meeting_types

```
meetings = user.user_meeting_types.where(meeting_type_id:7) #Select * from user_meeting_types where user_id = 37 and meeting_type_id = 7
```

Comment: It is working fine but when I apply with where conditions like this then it is not working: user = User.where('id'=>37)
   meetings = user.UserMeetingType.where('meeting_type_id'=>2)

Comment: From the model you posted you seem to have a problem with how rails naming conventions. Model name usually follow an upper camel case, while model relation follow a delimiter convention by underscore,and in particular has_many must refer to a plurar word ( the last word of the delimiter must be plural). If you don't follow convention then you must add extra code to relations for specifing how they are related to other models manually.